# programmatically show the logcat -b radio on app

Tags: android, logcat

I need to read and filter "logcat -b radio" log within my application

So I tried to write my code, but the result is empty. My cellphone has Android 6.0, please your help!

Comment: can you paste what you have tried ? so we can take a look at it and help you better :)

Comment: Please provide a [sample of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).